# Java JList listener

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jlist, listselectionlistener

What is wrong with my code.

I have created a JList, added items and pushed it to the left(BorderLayout.WEST). Every time a list item is clicked, i want a panel to be displayed to the right of the list. But the problem is when a list item is selected  and the listener is run, reaches to the if selection  where according to the index selected a panel related to it from another class (with inner classes) should be displayed(but it does not!) . . .

```
        import java.awt.BorderLayout;
        import java.awt.CardLayout;
        import java.awt.Color;
        import java.awt.Font;

        import javax.swing.JFrame;
        import javax.swing.JList;
        import javax.swing.JPanel;
        import javax.swing.ListSelectionModel;
        import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent;
        import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener;

    public class MainGUI extends JFrame{

    ListListeners listListeners = new ListListeners();

    JList list = new JList(
            new String[]{"Create Account","Borrow Book","Return Book","Add Book","Delete Book","Display Details"}
            );

    JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();

    public MainGUI()
    {
        CardLayout cardLayout = new CardLayout();
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        list.setForeground(Color.RED);
        list.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        list.setSelectionForeground(Color.GREEN);
        list.setSelectionBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        list.setFixedCellWidth(150);
        list.setFixedCellHeight(50);
        list.setFont(new Font("Serif",Font.BOLD,16));
        list.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        //add(listListeners.new  CreateAccount(panel1));
        //ListListeners.CreateAccount createAccount = listListeners.new  CreateAccount(panel1);
        //add(createAccount.createAccountPanel());          
        //registering the JList listener
        list.addListSelectionListener(new ListListener());
        panel.add(list);
        add(panel,BorderLayout.WEST);
    }

    class ListListener  extends JFrame implements ListSelectionListener
    {
        public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e)
        {
            int index = list.getSelectedIndex();
            if(e.getValueIsAdjusting() == false) {

                if (list.getSelectedIndex() == -1) {

                    System.out.println("No list item was selected");

                } else {


                    if(index == 0)
                    {

                        ListListeners.CreateAccount createAccount = listListeners.new  CreateAccount(panel1);
                        add(createAccount.createAccountPanel());

                        System.out.println(index);
                    }
                    else if(index == 1)
                    {
                        System.out.println(index);
                    }
                    else if(index == 2)
                    {
                        System.out.println(index);
                    }
                    else if(index == 3)
                    {
                        System.out.println(index);
                    }
                    else if(index == 4)
                    {
                        System.out.println(index);
                    }
                    else if(index == 5)
                    {
                        System.out.println(index);
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MainGUI frame = new MainGUI();

        frame.setSize(500, 350);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }    
}
```

This is another class with inner classes

```
    import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener;

public class ListListeners extends JFrame {

   class CreateAccount extends JPanel
   {           
       JLabel label = new JLabel("Enter new members' name : ");
       JTextField textField = new JTextField("This is a text field");          
       JRadioButton radioButton1 = new JRadioButton();
       JRadioButton radioButton2 = new JRadioButton();

       public CreateAccount(JPanel panel)
       {
           panel.add(label);
           panel.add(textField);
           panel.add(radioButton1,radioButton2);               
           add(panel,BorderLayout.CENTER);
       }

       public JPanel createAccountPanel()
       {
           JPanel panel = new JPanel();;
           panel.add(label);
           panel.add(textField);
           panel.add(radioButton1);            
           return panel;               
       }
   }

   class BorrowBook extends JPanel
   {
       public BorrowBook(JPanel panel)
       {
           JLabel label = new JLabel("Just borrow the book and go : ");
           JTextField textField = new JTextField("This is a second text field");   
           JRadioButton radioButton1 = new JRadioButton();
           JRadioButton radioButton2 = new JRadioButton();             
           panel.add(label);
           panel.add(textField);
           panel.add(radioButton1);
           panel.add(radioButton2);            
           add(panel,BorderLayout.CENTER);
       }
   }

   class ReturnBook extends JPanel
   {

   }

   class AddBook extends JPanel
   {

   }

   class DeleteBook extends JPanel
   {

   }

   class DisplayDetails extends JPanel
   {

   }
}
```

Comment: Please provide code that is only relevant to your question.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  BTW - why do both those classes extend frame?  It is usually unnecessary to extend a top-level container, but the bigger concern is that there is more than one frame.  See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/418556)

Answer (score 1):

Your ListListener class should not extend JFrame.

So you can't just use the add() method like you have it coded. You need a reference to the MainGui class because the is the frame where the JList is visible. So maybe you need to pass the frame as a parameter to the ListListener class.

Secondly, when you add components to a visible GUI the basic code structure is:

```
panel.add();
panel.revalidate();
panel.repaint();
```

because you need to tell the layout manager that a component has been added.

I would suggest you read the Swing tutorial on `How to Use Lists` for a working example that uses a ListSelectionListener. It will also give you a better design for you program.

Comment: If you know any of the tutorials please share them i will really appreciate

Comment: and to use CardLayout instead of add, remove, add, remove, the same JComponents on runtime,

Comment: @YunusEinsteinium, I did give you the tutorial name to search for. You can either find the tutorial by using Google or you can read the JList API where you will also find a link to the tutorial. Be proactive.